# Factorize $15a^2b^3 - 5a^3b^2 - 10a^4b$

Tags: factoring

I'm having problems with the factorization of $15a^2b^3 - 5a^3b^2 - 10a^4b$. I get stuck on step 2.

1: $15a^2b^3 - 5a^3b^2 - 10a^4b$

2: $5a^2b (3b^2 - ab - 2a^2)$

How do I factorize $3b^2 - ab - 2a^2$?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  this is the same as factoring $3x^2-x-2$, as with $x = \frac{a}b$, $3b^2-ab-2a^2 = a^2(3x^2-x-2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'AC' method , $$3 \cdot (-2) = -6$$

next find two numbers that multipply to $-6$ and sum to $-1$ , those two numbers are $-3$ , $2$. Now regroup like so ,

$$(3b^2 - 3ab) + (2ab - 2a^2)$$

Can you finish it now?